# App is crashing while using Boom Menu with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My application is using `RecyclerView` and inside `RecyclerView's` layout I have used [`Boom Menu`](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu).

I have used boom menu to provide these options to user:

[image: My <code>Boom Menu</code>]

The `RecyclerView` loads data from `Firebase` and all data loads successfully **except `Boom Menu`**

Which looks like this :

[image: My <code>RecyclerView</code>]

Only half of the time `Boom Menu` is visible and **Works** and when I click on the **Blank One** the app crashes with the following Error :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: The number of piece(3) is not equal to builders'(6)`

Here is my `XML` code :

```
<com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton
    android:id="@+id/fragment_home_article_boom_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:bmb_backgroundEffect="false"
    app:bmb_boomEnum="boomParabola_3"
    app:bmb_piecePlaceEnum="piecePlace_ham_3"
    app:bmb_buttonPlaceEnum="buttonPlace_ham_3"
    app:bmb_showDuration="1000"
    app:bmb_hideDuration="1000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Here is my `JAVA` Code **Inside `RecyclerView`'s Adapter** :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    View recyclerLayoutView = holder.view;
    BoomMenuButton fragmentHomePostBoomMenu = recyclerLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_article_boom_menu);
    assert fragmentHomePostBoomMenu != null;
    fragmentHomePostBoomMenu.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.Ham);
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentHomePostBoomMenu.getPiecePlaceEnum().pieceNumber(); i++) {

        HamButton.Builder hamButton = new HamButton.Builder()
                .normalImageRes(boomButtonIconList[i])
                .normalText(boomButtonTextList[i])
                .subNormalText(boomButtonSubTextList[i])
                .textGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
                .subTextGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
                .textSize(18)
                .subTextSize(14)
                .pieceColor(Color.rgb(169, 169, 169))
                .typeface(textTypeface)
                .subTypeface(subTextTypeface)
                .normalColor(boomButtonColorList[i])
                .normalTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
                .subNormalTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
                .imagePadding(new Rect(48, 48, 48, 48))
                .listener(new OnBMClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBoomButtonClick(int index) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, boomButtonTextList[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        fragmentHomePostBoomMenu.addBuilder(hamButton);
    }
```